# not equal to returning the incorrect result

Tags: python

for a project im working on im checking if a user inputted string is one of 4 strings, it checks if the user inputed one of these 4 strings if not it asks the user again. although when i try to run it,
if i enter str1 or any of the other ones it doesnt end the loop.

```
example = input('enter string')
while example != 'str1' or example != 'str2' or example != 'str3' or example != 'str4':
    print('input str1, str2, str3 or str4')
    example = input('enter string')
#do stuff
```

if i type str1

```
enter stringstr1
input str1, str2, str3 or str4
enter string
```

```
example = input('enter string')
while not example == 'str1' or not example == 'str2' or not example == 'str3' or not example == 'str4':
    print('input str1, str2, str3 or str4')
    example = input('enter string')
#do stuff
```

ive tried doing this because i thought it could be something to do with the while loop, not suprisingly it didnt fix it

Comment: The condition is always true because no matter the string you enter, one of the comparison will eb always be true, you're alays be different of one one the string, and as you use `OR` between them, one True is enough is make all True

Answer (score 2):

You're really looking for the opposite of `example == 'str1' or example == 'str2' or example == 'str3' or example == 'str4'`, which is `example != 'str1' and example != 'str2' and example != 'str3' and example != 'str4'`, because of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which are very useful to know for a programmer.

In your code, if `example == 'str1'`, then `example != 'str2'` would return `True`, and in a sequence of `or`-expressions, if one of the conditions is true, the whole expression is true.

A simpler way to do this is to check `example not in {'str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'}` instead, it's easier to read, easier to write and easier to get right.

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` condition will always return `true`

If you consider the truth table for `OR`

| example!='str1' | example!='str2' | example!='str3' | example!='str4 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | True | True |
| **False** | True | True | True | True |
| True | **False** | True | True | True |
| True | True | **False** | True | True |
| True | True | True | **False** | True |

*Note: the table is only partial because you can have any 1 input at a time in your code.*

What you want is for the last 4 row of the table to evaluate to `False`. Which by De Morgan's law would require you to use the `and` operator.

Consider the same table but for the `AND` operator.

| example!='str1' | example!='str2' | example!='str3' | example!='str4 | Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | True | True | True |
| **False** | True | True | True | False |
| True | **False** | True | True | False |
| True | True | **False** | True | False |
| True | True | True | **False** | False |

So, you will need to change your condition to:

`example!='str1' and example!='str2' and example!='str3' and example!='str4`

Similarly you can also change it to:

`not (example=='str1' or example=='str2' or exame=='str3' or example=='str4)`

I hope that helps.

For your code in Python, it is more Pythonic and reads better if you use the `in` operator.

`while example not in {'str1', 'str2', 'str3, 'str4'}:`

Answer (score 0):

Use `not in` to check inputed string and walrus operator `(:=)` to reduce redundancy.

```
while example := input('enter string') not in ('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'):
    print('input str1, str2, str3 or str4')
# do stuff
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply replace `or` by `and` everywhere (in your 1st snippet).

You could simplify the code by :

- using the `in` keyword
- set `example` to `None` before entering the loop

```py
example = None
while example not in ('str1', 'str2', 'str3', 'str4'):
    example = input('enter string')
```

Comment: Should be useful however.
It's basically just a fix to a wrong logical computation.